# SwiftUI - how to exclude inner `DragGesture` from outer `simultaneousGesture`?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uigesturerecognizer

I have a yellow button and a blue circle inside a gray container. I added [`DragGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/draggesture)s to both the circle and the container — however, the circle never moves.

This is the behavior that I want:

| Dragging the gray area | Dragging the button | Dragging the circle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The container moves | The container moves | The circle moves |

This is what I get:

| Dragging the gray area | Dragging the button | Dragging the circle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The container moves ✅ [image: The entire container moves] | The container moves ✅ [image: The entire container moves] | The container moves ❌ [image: The entire container moves, but only the circle should move] |

Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var containerOffset = CGSize.zero
    @GestureState var circleOffset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack { /// gray container
            
            /// should move the gray container when dragged
            Button {
                print("Button Pressed")
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
                    .padding(50)
                    .background(.yellow)
            }
            
            /// should **NOT** move the gray container when dragged
            /// How do I make it move the circle instead?
            Circle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(circleOffset)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture() /// this never gets called!
                        .updating($circleOffset) { value, circleOffset, transaction in
                            circleOffset = value.translation
                        }
                )
                .padding(50)
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .offset(containerOffset)
        .simultaneousGesture( /// `simultaneous` is needed to allow dragging from the yellow button
            DragGesture() /// move the gray container
                .updating($containerOffset) { value, containerOffset, transaction in
                    containerOffset = value.translation
                }
        )
    }
}
```

How do I stop the outer `DragGesture` from swallowing the inner circle's `DragGesture`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to add a state variable in `ContentView` that tracks whether the circle's gesture is active. When the circle's gesture is active, use a `GestureMask` of `.subviews` on the outer gesture to prevent it from activating. You can do it with an `@State`:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var containerOffset = CGSize.zero
    @GestureState var circleOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State var subviewDragIsActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack { /// gray container
            
            /// should move the gray container when dragged
            Button {
                print("Button Pressed")
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
                    .padding(50)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
            
            /// should **NOT** move the gray container when dragged
            /// How do I make it move the circle instead?
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(circleOffset)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture() /// this never gets called!
                        .updating($circleOffset) { value, circleOffset, transaction in
                            circleOffset = value.translation
                        }
                        .onChanged { _ in
                            subviewDragIsActive = true
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            subviewDragIsActive = false
                        }
                )
                .padding(50)
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .offset(containerOffset)
        .simultaneousGesture( /// `simultaneous` is needed to allow dragging from the yellow button
            DragGesture() /// move the gray container
                .updating($containerOffset) { value, containerOffset, transaction in
                    containerOffset = value.translation
                },
            including: subviewDragIsActive ? .subviews : .all
        )
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

or you can do it with an `@GestureState`:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var containerOffset = CGSize.zero
    @GestureState var circleOffset = CGSize.zero
    @GestureState var subviewDragIsActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack { /// gray container
            
            /// should move the gray container when dragged
            Button {
                print("Button Pressed")
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
                    .padding(50)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
            
            /// should **NOT** move the gray container when dragged
            /// How do I make it move the circle instead?
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(circleOffset)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture() /// this never gets called!
                        .updating($circleOffset) { value, circleOffset, transaction in
                            circleOffset = value.translation
                        }
                        .updating($subviewDragIsActive) {
                            _, flag, _ in
                            flag = true
                        }
                )
                .padding(50)
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .offset(containerOffset)
        .simultaneousGesture( /// `simultaneous` is needed to allow dragging from the yellow button
            DragGesture() /// move the gray container
                .updating($containerOffset) { value, containerOffset, transaction in
                    containerOffset = value.translation
                },
            including: subviewDragIsActive ? .subviews : .all
        )
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

If the circle is in a separately-defined `View` type, you should use an `@State` so you can pass down a `Binding`, like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct CircleView: View {
    @GestureState var circleOffset = CGSize.zero
    @Binding var dragIsActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .offset(circleOffset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture() /// this never gets called!
                    .updating($circleOffset) { value, circleOffset, transaction in
                        circleOffset = value.translation
                    }
                    .onChanged { _ in dragIsActive = true }
                    .onEnded { _ in dragIsActive = false }
                    )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var containerOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State var subviewDragIsActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack { /// gray container
            
            /// should move the gray container when dragged
            Button {
                print("Button Pressed")
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
                    .padding(50)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
            
            /// should **NOT** move the gray container when dragged
            /// How do I make it move the circle instead?
            CircleView(dragIsActive: $subviewDragIsActive)
                .padding(50)
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .offset(containerOffset)
        .simultaneousGesture( /// `simultaneous` is needed to allow dragging from the yellow button
            DragGesture() /// move the gray container
                .updating($containerOffset) { value, containerOffset, transaction in
                    containerOffset = value.translation
                },
            including: subviewDragIsActive ? .subviews : .all
        )
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

If any of several subviews might have a drag going on simultaneously (due to multitouch), you should probably use the preference system to pass their isActive states up to `ContentView`, but that's a significantly more complex implementation.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I had been wondering what [`GestureMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gesturemask) was for.